# http 404 from tomcat servlet in 'resources' path

Tags: java, path, mapping, ckeditor, servlet-3.0

I am use ckeditor ckfinder in my project.but i can not find ckfinder servlet when i use the default mapping.

i can find it ,if i change the mapping path in a short path.

```
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ckeditor</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.ckfinder.connector.ConnectorServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>XMLConfig</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>debug</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>ckeditor</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/resources/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

**when i use this that is http 404**

```
<url-pattern>/resources/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java</url-pattern>
```

**when i change it to short path ,i can got it:**

```
<url-pattern>/test/connector.java</url-pattern>
```

my environment is centeros6.5 tomcat7 jdk7(in windows environment i can got it in windows[window7 tomcat7])

The request is sent to

```
http://ip:8080/resources/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java
```

**Edit:**

`"Resources"` path lead to can not find the servlet, but I don't have other set of resources related content?

**I have a static directory 'Resources'**

anybody kown why?

Comment: What URL do you send your request to?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis http://ip:8080/resources/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i had fix my qusition~

Comment: Are you saying the long path doesn't work when requesting the long path, but the short path works when requesting the short path?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just test again, found in the directory containing resources when I can't find it, but I don't have the allocation of resources (static directory is contained in the resources directory)